# Why a different background color of selected option, depending on whether selection happens programmatically or by user click

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following select tag

```
<select id="s" size=3>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

When the user clicks on some of the options, the background color is the classic navy blue. But when I select an option programmatically, it's a gray color.

I have tried both

```
document.getElementById('s').getElementsByTagName('option')[1].selected = 'selected'
```

and

```
document.getElementById('s').selectedIndex = 1;
```

Why is this happening? Older Firefox versions work fine; the selected background color is always the navy blue, independently of how the option was selected. However, on newer versions of Firefox and Google Chrome, it's this shitty gray color when done programmatically.

Is there a way to fix this, other than resetting each time the background color of the options through a loop and setting the selected one to the desired navy blue? Why do the browsers make a distinction between user click and programmatic click?

Comment: It needs to have the focus as well: `document.getElementById('s').focus();`

Comment: thanks, should have thought about that